# custom auto number field + concatenate account name using flow but get syntax error

Tags: customsetting, quote, recordtriggeredflow

```
UPPER(LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,1})+trim( MID(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,FIND(" ",Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name),2))) &'/'&
Upper(LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Name ,1)+ trim(MID(Opportunity.Account.Name,FIND(" ",{Opportunity.Account.Name ),2)))
&'/'& 
Right ({!$Setup.TitaniumTekzi__c.TT_Quote_ID__c})
&'/'&TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))

&'-'&Right(Text((1+Year(Today()))),2)
```

Comment: Hi Babu, Welcome to SSE. Can you edit the question and post more details like what type of flow it is if record triggered flow is it on Opportunity and what syntax error you are getting here .

Answer (score 0):

The formula itself have some errors:

- Unecessary `}` character
- Unecessary `{` character

After removing these unecessary characters you'll get more descriptive Error Messages, like the `RIGHT()` function, which is lacking the second parameter

Below you find it with some indentation, to facilitate the reading, but still with problems

```
UPPER(
    LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,1})
    +
    trim(MID(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,FIND(" ",Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name),2))
) 
&'/'&
Upper(
    LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Name ,1)
    + 
    trim(MID(Opportunity.Account.Name,FIND(" ",{Opportunity.Account.Name ),2))
)
&'/'& 
Right({!$Setup.TitaniumTekzi__c.TT_Quote_ID__c})
&'/'&
TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
&'-'&
Right(Text((1+Year(Today()))),2)
```

And here the same code but without errors, you can paste both in a diff tool (like [Mergely](https://editor.mergely.com/)) to see exactly what have changed

```
UPPER(
    LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,1)
    +
    trim(MID(Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name,FIND(" ",Opportunity.Account.Parent.Name),2))
) 
&'/'&
Upper(
    LEFT(Opportunity.Account.Name ,1)
    + 
    trim(MID(Opportunity.Account.Name,FIND(" ",Opportunity.Account.Name ),2))
)
&'/'& 
Right({!$Setup.TitaniumTekzi__c.TT_Quote_ID__c}, 2)
&'/'&
TEXT(YEAR(TODAY()))
&'-'&
Right(Text((1+Year(Today()))),2)
```